# What is the difference in Google Cloud between cloudbuild.yaml and cloudmigrate.yaml?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am building a basic pipeline on GCP with Cloud Builder and I have come across articles and examples where there was used one or the other. Is there any difference in functionality-wise or it is just a naming convention?

Comment: Where did you find a cloudmigrate.yaml file? Can you paste the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming is for readability and to show purpose of the YAML.The naming of the configuration file can adopt the best practice or convention you (or your company) follows, and can be used as parameter for the flag “config”.

In this reference at GCP [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#first_deployment_of_the_application) uses “cloudmigrate.yaml” as an example:

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudmigrate.yaml
    --substitutions _INSTANCE_NAME=INSTANCE_NAME,_REGION=REGION
```

When you look up at the GCP Cloud Run command documentation[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit), the flag allows to call any YAML or JSON file to use as the build configuration file, with “cloudbuild.yaml" as the default.

`--config=CONFIG`; default="cloudbuild.yaml"

[1] https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#first_deployment_of_the_application

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit